# Why does argparse only work if the python interpreter is called explicitly?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, argparse

I have the python interpreter location in my path environment variable so that I don't need to explicitly call the python interpreter from the command line. However, when I use the argparse module to read command line arguments, it only works if I explicitly call the python interpreter.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('w')

cmd_args = parser.parse_args()

print(cmd_args.w)
```

when I don't explicitly call the interpreter, this occurs:

```
C:\Users\nheme\Desktop> command_line_parse.py test_argument
usage: command_line_parse.py [-h] w
command_line_parse.py: error: the following arguments are required: w
```

When I explicitly call the interpreter, the code works as expected:

```
C:\Users\nheme\Desktop> python command_line_parse.py test_argument
test_argument
```

Why do I need to explicitly call the interpreter?

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows, and a `shebang line`.  That requires an extra step:  https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#arguments-in-shebang-lines.  It used to be that Windows also required some sort `$1 $2 $3...` to pass arguments, but that's old.

Comment: Running a .py file directly is implemented by calling `ShellExecuteEx`, which is based on a complex web of registry settings that are spread across many keys in both the system and per-user registry hives. There are many points of potential failure here.

Comment: Start by trying to fix the .py file association using the GUI. You can use the control panel or the "open with" "choose another app" dialog. Make sure it's set to "Python" with a rocket on the icon, which should be the py.exe launcher as configured by the "Python.File" ProgId, which should be set up to pass command line arguments, unless some other program messed with it.

Comment: @eryksun I've already set the default program to run .py files as the python.exe but I am still required to call the interpreter explicitly

Comment: Presumably you by browsed for the python.exe executable. That's the wrong thing to do. It creates an automatic ProgId that doesn't support command-line arguments and also loses all of the other configured associations for the Python.File ProgId, such as the drag and drop handler for script files.